# ES6 javascript constant-return error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

running lint on a test module is stating an error :

```
module.exports = (x) => {
  if (x % 2 === 0) {
    return 'even';
  } else if (x % 2 === 1) {
    return 'odd';
  } else if (x > 100) {
    return 'big';
  } else if (x < 0) {
    return 'negative';
  }
};
```

running ESLint :

```
> yarn lint
../server/modules/my-awesome-module.js (1/0)
✖  3:22  Expected to return a value at the end of this function  consistent-return
✖ 1 error (7:35:56 PM)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

what is the correct ES6 coding in this case ?
thanks for feedback

Comment: If it’s not the case that `x % 2 === 0`, `x % 2 === 1`, `x > 100`, or `x < 0` – for example, when x is 55.5 – what should be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an `else` case. If none of your `if` or `else if` conditions are met, there is no return value.

You could easily add a default `else` block or just a simple return at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that based on some code paths (any of the if/else clauses), a value might be returned by the function. however, in cases where none of the cases match (for example, where x=50.5), nothing is returned. For consistency purposes, something should be returned by the function.

An example solution would be:

```
module.exports = (x) => {
  if (x % 2 === 0) {
    return 'even';
  } else if (x % 2 === 1) {
    return 'odd';
  } else if (x > 100) {
    return 'big';
  } else if (x < 0) {
    return 'negative';
  }

  return 'none'
};
```

Comment: Justin's answerthanks .. that's what I stand in my comment to

Answer (score 0):

You can consider changing the code snippet as

```js
module.exports = (x) => {
  var result = "";
  if (x % 2 === 0) {
    result = "even";
  } else if (x % 2 === 1) {
    result = "odd";
  } else if (x > 100) {
    result = "big";
  } else if (x < 0) {
    result = "negative";
  }
  return result;
};
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks... actually my snippet was written to fail... and then changing the order of the  if clauses to handle correctly the result... thanks